# Xpath exists in chrome, but not in my script. no such element: Unable to locate element:

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, instagram

I am trying to find the button element by xpath, which is found when I type it in chrome, but the script gives me the no attribute id error. I have tried switching into an iframe and frame, I have used webdriver.wait to wait for the button element to show and none of those work. I would also like to cycle through and click the first button if it says "Follow" and then move to the next button if it says "Follow".The Script runs on chrome and I am trying to do this on instagram [Html here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbdC1.png)

```
 popup = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]')

 ActionChains(browser)\
.move_to_element(popup).click()\
.perform()
```

`File "/Users/trevaroneill/PycharmProjects/Insta/instafollow.py", line 91, in <module>
    popup = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]')`

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]"}
```

Comment: Please share the URL

Comment: the error you're seeing is normal as the list has no attribute named id

Comment: can you give some html code? and script run on chrome too?

Comment: best guess, that html was modified by javascript before you view them in your debugger, and the button doesn't have the `_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0` classes before the javascript messes with them - or maybe even the button don't exist at all

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using find_element**s**, you should rather write:

```
 ActionChains(browser)\
.move_to_element(popup[0]).click()\
.perform()
```

in order to access first element of the list returned by find_elements.

The problem is if you have several webelements selected by your xpath, in this case, it is not sure that the first one is the one you actually aim at. I would suggest you use **find_element** if there are no particular reason for which you are using find_elements

Comment: Does not work stil, I get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)

Comment: My guess in this case, is an uncorrect  xpath, several possibilities:
1) _qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0  looks like a class name that is generated dynamically. Make sure it is still present when debugging your test, as @YoavGaudin has suggested it.
2) try to reformulate you xpath. use sommething different that the class attribute.. or the button node.
3) has the DOM been fully downloaded when you try to reach the element ? an implicit wait could help if not.

the best would be to have the html source or the link to the page you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the wanted element in a list.

change
`popup = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//button[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]')`

into
`popup = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]')`

`find_element` and not `find_elements`.

Comment: Does not work stil, I get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]"} (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)

Comment: There's a problem with your xpath then. 
Make sure a button with class "_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0" exists at the time the code is executed (use any debugger).

Also, you can test your xpath in any browser's inspecting mode in the "console" tab. Type in the console input `document.getElementsByClassName(<className>)`